# What will happen when updating the Production view in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I have Couchbase view named `getDetails` which returns the data about document's that have the prefix `DD`. Suppose I update the production view `getDetails` at the same time as my application inserts a new document with the prefix `DD`. Does that impact Updating (indexing) the View getDeatails.